In Google Cloud Run Jobs Log, What Does Log Severity Level Default Mean?
Job Details
Python code, containerised as an image in the Google Artefact Registry, being triggered daily with a scheduler trigger.
Logging Mechanism
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

import logging 

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S, %d-%b-%Y', level=logging.DEBUG)

# Start logging events to STDOUT or STDERR 
logging.info(msg='This is an info level log.')
...

Outcome
The job is executed successfully. But when I go to the GCP console to look at the logs, the choice of severity levels does not seem to filter my logs. Look at this screenshot.

It gives some other logging messages that I cannot interpret.
I thought it should give me all INFO level logs, as in messages that appear in my code like the snippet above.
But I see all logs from my application when pick Default severity level.

Questions

When I pick severity level Info or Debug, where do the logs come from, as it seems they are not from my application.
Why am I seeing all the logs from my application when I select severity level Default? How can I see logs of a specific severity level?
Does my application have to log at the most detailed level for all of them to surface on the GCP log? What if my application code says

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S, %d-%b-%Y', level=logging.INFO)

Are my Debug logs gone then?

Please try to limit questions to one question.
See Setting up Cloud Logging for Python
Your program's output will be formatted by Python's logging package and written to stdout where it is captured by Cloud Logging.
As a result, you'll end up with a default (not-specified) severity log entry timestamped (!) by Cloud Logging with a text payload that contains your log message which includes the timestamp (which will be different), INFO and your message, viz:
00:00:00, 29-Jul-2024|INFO: This is an info level log.

This is probably not what you want.
If you want the simplest logging, just output to stdout and trust that it will be captured by the compute service and Cloud Logging logged.
If you want more control (over timestamps, severity, labels, JSON|text etc) then, per the referenced document, you'll need to bind the Python logger to Cloud Logging.
